# Is that possible to use script to change the preference inside global info

Tags: dm-script

all:
I'd like to use script to change the preference of Save Image inside Global Info. I'd like to change it to "Ignore the annotation(s)" before saving image. But I didn't find any useful information in the manual. If someone knows how to change it, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Chen ZX
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, there is no officially supported script interface to these Save Image preference parameters. However, there are undocumented global tags that store their current values. One can access and change these global tags, but whether such changes will actually produce the desired result depends on the version of GMS and details of how your script is written and executed. So consider the following example as something to try, but please note that it may not quite work as you wish in your particular context.

```
TagGroup globalTagGroup = GetPersistentTagGroup();
String tagPath = "Private:Save Image:Burn Annotation Option";
Number burnAnnotationOption;
globalTagGroup.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber(tagPath, burnAnnotationOption);
OKDialog("Current burn annotation option for Save Image: " + burnAnnotationOption);

Number ignoreAnnotationOption = 0;
globalTagGroup.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber(tagPath, ignoreAnnotationOption);
```

Note that this global tag is under the "Private" heading. Generally, it is safe enough to read such tags to get at the current settings of internal DM parameters, but changing such parameters by setting the associated tag is not supported and does not always work as one would like.

Comment: Amending this good answer: You can think of the global tags just like a file on disk. The time when the information is "read/written" by the application isn't altered by changing the value. Some functionality only reads once on GMS startup, and writes once on GMS shut-down, other things read from the preferences "on demand" whenever needed.  If it is the latter, changing global tags helps. If it is the first, it doesn't.